Use mouse wheel to scroll the windows form
I am creating a report in C# using PDFSharp versions 1.51 and 1.52.
I want the mouse wheel to scroll the report.
I have a form in which I am calling another form and displaying the graphics in PDFSharp's pagepreview.
I want to implement scrolling using a mouse wheel, but only the event is triggering not actual scrolling.
My code is attached below:
ReportOptionsForm.cs
private ReportGenerator reportGenerator;
PreviewReportForm previewForm = new PreviewReportForm(reportGenerator);

ReportGenerator  is one of my classes.
PreviewReportForm.cs
public PreviewReportForm(ReportGenerator rg)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(957, 739);

    this.Text = Language.Strings.PreviewReport;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    this.ControlBox = true;    // right corner control symbols, ???
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(60, 60, 60);
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

    reportGenerator = rg;


    
    InitializeControls();
    
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}


private void InitializeControls()
{
    numberOfPages = reportGenerator.TotalPages;

    pageSplitBarHeight = 6;

    reportPagePreview = new PagePreview();
    reportPagePreview.TabIndex = 4;
    reportPagePreview.Parent = this;
    reportPagePreview.PageSize = new XSize(612, 792 * numberOfPages + pageSplitBarHeight * (numberOfPages - 1));
    reportPagePreview.ZoomPercent = 180;
    reportPagePreview.Size = new Size(957, 673);
    reportPagePreview.Location = new Point(0, actionToolStrip.Bottom);
    reportPagePreview.PageColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    reportPagePreview.Zoom = Zoom.BestFit;
    reportPagePreview.ZoomPercent = 100;

    reportPagePreview.MouseWheel += ReportPagePreview_MouseWheel;
 
    reportRenderer = new ReportRenderer(reportGenerator, reportPagePreview.DesktopColor, pageSplitBarHeight);
    reportPagePreview.SetRenderFunction(reportRenderer.Render);


    UpdateStatusStrip();
}

private void ReportPagePreview_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta != 0)
    {

        int delta = e.Delta > 0 ? -120 : 120; 


        int currentScrollPosition = reportPagePreview.VerticalScroll.Value;


        int newScrollPosition = Math.Max(reportPagePreview.VerticalScroll.Minimum,
                                          Math.Min(reportPagePreview.VerticalScroll.Maximum,
                                          currentScrollPosition + delta));

        // Set the new scroll position
        reportPagePreview.VerticalScroll.Value = newScrollPosition;
    }
    reportPagePreview.Invalidate();
}

I have tried this method. but not working. How can I solve this or is there any other method

Are you using the original PDFsharp? There is version 1.32, version 1.51, and version 6.1, but there is no version 1.52. The latest versions should support mouse-wheel scrolling out of the box, but I suspect you are using version 1.32 from year 2012.
